# Unique Element only in Order Indicator

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, unique-constraint, xmlschema

Is there a way to make elements unique in same sequence (choice, all) but not on the whole document.

For example this should work (Both John and Jane have Francis as middlename):

```
<students xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="stack.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <middlename>Francis</middlename>
        <middlename>Mike</middlename>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <middlename>Francis</middlename>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    </student>
</students>
```

But this should not work (John has two similar middle names):

```
<students xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="stack.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <middlename>Francis</middlename>
        <middlename>Francis</middlename>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    </student>
</students>
```

I have tried so far following on my .xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="students">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="student">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5">
                                <xs:element name="middlename" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        
        <xs:unique name="middlename_unique">
            <xs:selector xpath="student/middlename"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."></xs:field>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But this only makes middlename in general unique not for a single student...

Comment: Do you use XSD 1 or 1.1? In 1.1 an assertion might be able to express your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#specifyingUniqueness says

> XML Schema enables us to indicate that any attribute or element value
> must be unique within a certain scope. To indicate that one particular
> attribute or element value is unique, we use the unique element first
> to "select" a set of elements, and then to identify the attribute or
> element "field" relative to each selected element that has to be
> unique within the scope of the set of selected elements.

So I think you want

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="students">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="student">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5">
                                <xs:element name="middlename" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="middlename_unique">
                        <xs:selector xpath="middlename"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="."/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```